# Telegram Bot /getUpdates and parse JSON response?

Tags: python, json, telegram, telegram-bot

I am looking to parson the JSON response from executing the Telegram API call: `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getUpdates`

From that response, I want to store all the chat_IDs somewhere. I would like to loop through all those IDs to send a message via the bot into each group chat.

```
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):

    bot_token = ''
    bot_chatID = ''
    bot_message = ''

    get_updates = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_chatID + '/getUpdates'
    response = requests.get(get_updates)
    final = json.loads(response.text)

    Dict = {final['result']['update_id']}


    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()
```

I know I am not creating this dictionary from the response correctly. How do I create this dictionary or array correctly and then loop through that object to send the `bot_message` in each of those groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is an array of objects, you can use this kind of code to loop through it

```
 Dict = final['result']

 for obj in Dict:
   print(obj['update_id'])
```

I tested this, if you want to read the `message` then

```
   obj['message']['text']
```